# Javascript to disable resize option

Tags: javascript

I have written this javascript code to open a webpage in new window without maximize option.
But still than the maximize option is not disabled.

```
    function OpenNewWindow() {
            var a1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
            var a2 = document.getElementById('TextBox2').value;
            var a3 = document.getElementById('TextBox3').value;
            var a4 = document.getElementById('TextBox4').value;
            var a5 = document.getElementById('TextBox5').value;
            var a6 = document.getElementById('TextBox6').value;
            var a7 = document.getElementById('TextBox7').value;
            var a8 = document.getElementById('TextBox8').value;
            var a9 = document.getElementById('TextBox9').value;
            var a10 = document.getElementById('TextBox10').value;
            var a11 = document.getElementById('TextBox11').value;
            var a12 = document.getElementById('TextBox12').value;
            var a13 = document.getElementById('TextBox13').value;
            var a14 = document.getElementById('TextBox14').value;
            var a15 = document.getElementById('TextBox15').value;
            var a16 = document.getElementById('TextBox16').value;
            var a17 = document.getElementById('TextBox17').value;
            var a18 = document.getElementById('TextBox18').value;
            var a19 = document.getElementById('TextBox19').value;
            var a20 = document.getElementById('TextBox20').value;
            var a21 = document.getElementById('TextBox21').value;
            var a22 = document.getElementById('TextBox22').value;
            var a23 = document.getElementById('TextBox23').value;
            window.open('PaymentReceipt.aspx?Parameter1=' + a1 + '&Parameter2=' + a2 + '&Parameter3=' + a3 + '&Parameter4=' + a4 + '&Parameter5=' + a5 + '&Parameter6=' + a6 + '&Parameter7=' + a7 + '&Parameter8=' + a8 + '&Parameter9=' + a9 + '&Parameter10=' + a10 + '&Parameter11=' + a11 + '&Parameter12=' + a12 + '&Parameter13=' + a13 + '&Parameter14=' + a14 + '&Parameter15=' + a15 + '&Parameter16=' + a16 + '&Parameter17=' + a17 + '&Parameter18=' + a18 + '&Parameter19=' + a19 + '&Parameter20=' + a20 + '&Parameter21=' + a21 + '&Parameter22=' + a22 + '&Parameter23=' + a23, '_blank', 'location=no, resizable=no');
        }
```

Please tell me where is the mistake why the maximize option is not disable

Comment: you may want to look into [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: In short - you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `resizable=no` works with IE,but not in Firefox. By default Firefox windows are always resizable. but you can try this in your `PaymentReceipt` page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function () {
       window.resizeTo(300, 300);
    }
    window.onload = function () {
       window.resizeTo(300, 300);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: but you can maximize and minimize the window but resize is not possible